# Laravel relationship error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id on line 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two models `Company` and `Employee`, with corresponding tables in MySQL, `companies`, and `employees`.

I have these Many-to-One relationships defined:

In the `Company` model:

```
 public function employees(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee','company');
    }
```

In the `Employee` model:

```
public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company');
    }
```

`company` above in the methods is an unsigned integer foreign key present in the `employees` table.

In tinker I have tried `$company->employees;`, which returns a list of all the employees in the selected company. However, when I do `$company->employees->id` to get the IDs of all the employees only and not the other rows, it gives me the error:

```
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id on line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `$company->employees` returns a collection, `->id` is not a property in the collection, thats why you get the error.

If you want to retrieve an array containing all the id's of your employees you might do this:

```
$company->employees()->lists('id');
```

If you're reading this and using laravel `^5.3.*` then the answer would be:

```
$company->employees()->pluck('id');
```

This would return a collection with all id's, if you want it to be an array you can chain the `->toArray()` behind it.

Comment: That works, could you please explain the lists method a bit? thanks!

Comment: What I also am confused about, is that, `id` is a property as it's a field on the table, or is it not?

Comment: Certainly, the [lists](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) function returns an array containing all your id's, `id` is indeed a property, but your results looks a bit like this `$x = array(array('id' => 1));`, you were trying to do `$x['id']` while the `id` value was actually in `$x[0]['id']`

Comment: Okay, but like the way it is described on the Laravel documentation , shouldn't I be able to do `$employees->company->id` the way they do `echo $comment->post->title;` there?

Comment: Depends on the type of relation, you have a `hasMany` so your result is always a collection, in the example its a single result because it only belongs to one relation.

Comment: Okay, but when I do `$employee->company->id`, it gives me the error `PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1`, even though every employee has only one company.